# Would a USB Ethernet adapter use the same drivers as the on-board Ethernet port?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ethernet

My issue is this: I turned installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2009 Macbook Pro. I am having an issue with the forcedeth drivers that run my ethernet port, mainly that they don't work. I can get an adhoc connection to pass connectivity to the linux machine, but it won't get a signal plugged straight into my gateway. I have tried numerous solutions with the drivers and the thing still wont connect, so I've moved on to workarounds.

My question is if I used a USB Ethernet dongle, would it use the same drivers as my regular ethernet port? I'm not sure if this is a valid workaround or an instance of me not fully understanding how Ubuntu deals with hardware.

Comment: When you buy a USB dongle use the driver specific for it. Mainstream products will be plug and play.

Comment: So you are confirming that the dongle will use different driver to establish a connection? Or are you just saying that I'll need to install drivers if I do get the dongle?

Comment: I'm saying when you buy one if the good dongles Ubuntu will automatically load the correct driver as soon as it is plugged in. If its a realtec or broadcom dongle though manual work maybe required to download drivers and some of them need to be compiled. Search this site for 'USB WiFi' for problems some have had.

Comment: At least that's the way I think it works. My WiFi is built-in Intel with no problems.

Comment: my wifi is broadcom, which I think I can update. However, I'm running the Ubuntu machine as a server so I really want a wired connection for it.